# Matching appropiate current value for components

Tags: led, current, components

I was looking around the site and I encountered an intresting answer.The one who posted it said that:"If you supply too much current to a device,it will draw as much as it needs" and also that if you give a smaller amount,it is possible to damage it.Now I remember that I tested a LED with a higher current(a significant number of mili-amps past the operating spec) and it wasn't really affected in the way I expected it to be.It looked to be just a little dimmer than usual.Is it true that only less supplied current would damage a device/component and not a higher one?It sounds absurd to me,but I just wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most products and many components such as ICs are designed to operate from a constant voltage supply. They will draw what current they need, provided the voltage is in the correct range.

A device that is supplied with a 19V 5A adapter will operate properly from a 19V 100A power supply (assuming it meets any other requirements) and will draw no more than 5A. It may not operate properly from a 19V 4A supply. It may not operate properly from a 15V 10A supply or a 24V 5A supply (and either case could damage it).

LEDs are designed to operate at a certain **current**, not voltage. An external circuit (maybe just a resistor) is typically used to allow them to operate from a constant voltage. If you supply more than the rated current to an LED you may well damage it. It may get brighter, to some extent until internal heating and damage reduce the brightness, permanently if you go too far.

The analogous case with LEDs is that if you supply an LED from a constant-current supply of (say) 15mA it will take the *voltage* it needs. That might be 3.1V for a white LED or 1.9V for a red LED. The fact the constant-current supply is capable of 3.5V or 350V won't change the LED voltage.

Comment: So that means not all devices work on the take-as-much-current-as-you-need concept.Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A typical constant-voltage power supply marked "12 V, 100 W" isn't trying to push 100 W of power into the load. It produces a fixed 12 V output voltage. 100 W is just the maximum power it can deliver without overheating or malfunctionning. The actual power drawn depends on the characteristics of the load connected to it.

The amount of power P drawn by a component from a source of constant voltage U depends on the component's resistance R: P = U * I and I = U / R, so P = (U^2)/R.

Some loads have a fixed resistance. So for a fixed supply voltage they will consume a fixed amount of power (regardless of the maximum power rating of the supply), and if you double the voltage they will consume four times the power. In this case you just need to regulate the input voltage according to the specifications and the component will draw the "right" power.

But not all components behave like this. Sometimes their resistance will vary depending on various factors.

Many electronic devices incorporate a regulator. The regulator has a resistance that *increases* as the input voltage increases, to guarantee that the power drawn by the load remains the same even if the input voltage changes! So the specification for the device will instead give you a range of acceptable input voltages.

A LED has an (almost) infinite resistance below its turn-on voltage. As voltage increases above that threshold its resistance *decreases* very quickly. Because the decrease in resistance is very steep, you would need to set the input voltage very precisely to control the power going through the LED. And because it also depends on the LED temperature and varies between LEDs of the same model (variability in the fabrication process), you actually can't rely on setting a fixed input voltage. There are two options:

- You can use an additional resistor in series that is much larger than the typical LED resistance, so that the variations in LED resistance become negligible and you can rely on setting a fixed input voltage. This is simple, but a lot of power is wasted in that resistor.
- Or you can use an additional circuit called a constant-current regulator (or LED driver) that senses the actual current going through the LED and continuously adapts the voltage so that that current remains constant. This is more complex (instead of a passive resistor, you have an active current controller) but more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that you are thinking of current and voltage as two independent things.

Remember, V=I*R. So, if your load "R" is supplied with a high voltage, we will see also see a large current. Same case occurs when we apply a small voltage, we will see a that "R" draws a small amount of current.

In the case of an LED, it is driven by current. If we supply a controlled current source, we can slowly increase the current and see that the brightness will increase until it heats up too much a blows.

Now let's talk about a general load. For example a toaster. If you leave the toaster in the plug (In Canada its 120VAC @ 60Hz) but DO NOT turn your toaster on, it will draw little current to no current. It still "sees" a large voltage, but the switch is open and will not allow current to draw.

In the case that you start toasting, all of a sudden you close the internal circuit and a current will be drawn with respect to its load. This may be were you are confused. Here we can say "it draws the current it needs", but that is basically just saying that the load is attached and the voltage applied on the load will result in a proportional current.

Hope that helps.

-Josh

Comment: Let's consider a fixed voltage source(a battery) and a component.The voltage matches the specs but the current is past the indications(the resistance is too low).Here,in this case,will the component be damaged?

Comment: As long as the voltage meets the spec, it will not be damaged. The Imax and Vmax limits are for current and voltage supplies respectively.

Comment: Ok,but how about a lower current than needed.How can it damage devices?

Comment: Lower current will never damage a device. Think about it this way, if we supply the lowest current possible (0 Amps), the device is turned off. So absolutely no damage. Damage occurs when current is high and the device starts to heat up.